# Average and dummy value in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Iam beginner in python
I have a `dataframe`:

```
df
Road_Section    RoadType    Speed   Landuse
Zone1           Local       1.33    Shops
Zone1           National    0.37    Field
Zone1           Collector   0.52    Park
Zone1           National    1.17    Resident
Zone1           Local       1.21    Office
Zone2           Local       0.52    Park
Zone2           Local       1.05    Shops
Zone2           Collector   2.48    Shops
```

I calculate of speed each zone using this code:

```
df.groupby("Zone")['speed'].mean()
```

However, I couldn’t find how to make simultaneous to calculate the average of the speed each zone and change to `RoadType` and `Landuse` columns into dummy value. The dummy value for 1 is in the zone and 0 not in the zone.

```
Zone    Average_Speed   Local   National    Collector   Shops   Office  Resident    Park    Field
Zone1   0.92            1       1           1           1       1       1           1       1                  
Zone2   1.35            1       0           1           1       0       0           1       0
```

Is there anyone can help me how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create index first [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with `Road_Section`. Then create `mean` per first column, and join another DataFrame created by [`get_dummies`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html) with `max`:

```
df1 = df.set_index('Road_Section')
mean = df1.pop('Speed').mean(level=0).to_frame('Average_Speed')

df = mean.join(pd.get_dummies(df1, prefix='', prefix_sep='').max(level=0)).reset_index()
print (df)
  Road_Section  Average_Speed  Collector  Local  National  Field  Office  \
0        Zone1           0.92          1      1         1      1       1   
1        Zone2           1.35          1      1         0      0       0   

   Park  Resident  Shops  
0     1         1      1  
1     1         0      1
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. what it means this part `prefix='', prefix_sep=''`?

Comment: @Arief Be free omit it, then are changed columns names in get dummies with `RoadType` and `Landuse` with separator `_`. So it is use for remove it.